# Problema ao exibir imagem dentro de modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, imagem

Preciso exibir em uma modal uma lista das imagens selecionadas, porém ela é exibida apenas após clicar (dar o foco) em algum local na modal.

Trechos do código:

HTML:

```
<label>Imagens: </label>
<fieldset class="">
    <div class="divImg" ng-repeat="item in modelCheckList.listImagens" id="ID_{{item.nome}}" ng-click="">
        <img width="40px" height="30px" src="{{item.imagem}}">
        <button ng-click="removeImg($index)" type="button" class="botaoCancelaImg"><span
                aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(fileContents => {
for (let index = 0; index < fileContents.length; index++) {
    $scope.modelCheckList.listImagens.push({ id, idCheckList, 'base64': fileContents[index], nome: nomeArq[index]})
}
});
```

Comment: Sem seu código completo fica difícil ajudar. Acredito que seja um problema bem comum do próprio angularjs. Tenta dar um `$scope.apply()` depois do for, isso deve forçar o angular atualizar os valores.

Comment: @edsonalves Estes trechos são as únicas partes que envolvem o preenchimento da lista e e a exibição na modal. Mas era isto mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: É que neste caso só daria pra ter certeza testando o código todo. Que bom que deu certo! Disponha.

Comment: Experimente usar `ng-src="{{image}}"` no lugar de `src="{{image}}"`.